# Как сделать функцию открытия файла?

Tags: c#

Нужна функция, открывающая файл в бинарном виде, и , если такой файл существует, нужно что-то передать другой функции, которая перезапишет файл особым образом, сохранит и закроет поток.
Как такое сотворить? Что именно и как нужно передавать?
Пока что есть такое:

```
static int OpenFile(string filePath)
    {
        do
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter correct file name (full path):");
        filePath = Console.ReadLine();
        }while(System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)!=true);
    }
```

Штука еще в том, что нужно открыть любой тип файла(не только текстовые) и ,желательно, в виде строки из ноликов и единичек.

Comment: > в виде строки из ноликов и единичек

До этой точки мне казалось, что я понимаю ваш вопрос.

Comment: Возможно я не так выразился. Все данные хранятся в бинарном виде, так? Т.е. эти самые нолики и единички. Вот они-то мне и нужны.

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov так у Вас там и так будут нолики и единички. Даже в текстовом файле. Если Вы спрашиваете, как прочитанные данные вывести на экран/в файл в двоичном виде, то так и скажите

Comment: М... мне надо сделать "реверс" файла, т.е. нолики заменить на единички, а единички на нолики.

Comment: Ну преобразование из char в int/uint неявное, а обратно -- только явное. Посмотрите http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289792/int-to-char-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть много методов. Простейший вариант такой:

```
try
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < bytes.Length; idx++)
        bytes[idx] = (byte)~bytes[idx];
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    // do nothing, file doesn't exist
}
```

Учтите, что этот вариант

- неэкономно использует память
- не справляется с очень-очень длинными файлами (длиной больше 2Г)
- не проверяет ошибки
- не справляется с read-only и тому подобными штуками
- не учитывает возможный race condition, если несколько процессов «сражаются» за содержимое файла

---

В качестве довольно сложного, но более эффективного метода, вы можете попробовать [memory-mapped file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) (там в конце есть подходящий пример кода).